# How can I enable alt-spacebar window menu?

Tags: release-freya, window-management

I recently switched to Elementary from Ubuntu as day-today distro. But I'm not able to use alt-spacebar menu, if I want to maximize or minimize the window. It's just I hate going over arrow keys. Yeah! Long time Vimmer!
Thanks.

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but you could assign alt-space to 'Toggle Maximised' in SystemSettings -> Keyboard -> Windows.

Comment: At the moment, I'm using it. Again, I'm accustomed to the menu. I've use it extensively for window management. Thanks though, for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Alt-Spacebar as a hotkey for toggling maximized or any other entry, this should revert Alt-Space behavior to what you are accustomed to.

By default for me Alt-Spacebar was mapped to Next Keyboard Layout in *Keyboard* > *Universal* Access, by disabling this the window menu took over properly.